# how can I have a collapsible button to show for mobile only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For large screen I want just the list to show without the collapsible button and when it comes to mobile I want this button to show just like this. I've tried putting `hidden-lg` or `visible-xs` on the `button` tag but it deletes the whole row for the large screen. How can I have a collapsible button to show for mobile only ? Thanks in advance!

```
 <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show
    </button>

    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      <ol class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Warrior</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Adventurer</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Mage</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

custom.js

```
$(function(){
  $('#demo').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show');
  })
  $('#demo').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Hide');
  })
})
```

I've also tried

```
#demo{
    display: none;    
}

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    #demo{
        display: block;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Deebs, I expanded on your proposal since I believe the expected behavior in mobile would be for the `#demo` div to be hidden and to be shown/hidden when clicking on `#button`.

```js
// Pure JS
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var disp = document.getElementById("demo1").style.display;
    document.getElementById("demo1").style.display = disp === "" || disp == "none" ? "block" : "none";
    this.innerHTML = disp === "" || disp === "none" ? "Hide" : "Show";
});

// jQuery
$("#button2").on("click", function() {
    $("#demo2").toggle();
    $("#button2").text( $("#demo2").css("display") === "block" ? "Hide" : "Show" );
});
```

```css
#demo1, #demo2 {
    display:none;
}
#button1, #button2 {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Pure JS:</strong></p>
<button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show</button>
<div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    <ol class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Warrior</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Adventurer</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Mage</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<p><strong>jQuery:</strong></p>
<button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show</button>
<div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    <ol class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Warrior</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Adventurer</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Mage</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The verbiage of your question is a little confusing... and your media query looks funky.  Try

```
#demo{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
    #demo{
        display: block;    
    }
}
```

This will keep the demo div hidden on screens smaller than 780px, and visible on screens wider than 780px.  If you want to hide/show the button itself, you'd have to add that CSS as well.